# XMPP Protocol on XAMPP

Tags: web-development, xampp

Hey I was wondering if I could use the XMPP messaging protocol in the Mac application XAMPP.

Comment: Here are a list of xmpp servers you can use. http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/.  ejabberd is certainly one of the most popular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAMPP is "Apache, MySQL, PHP (+PHPMyAdmin), Perl" and is just a software bundle containing the basic programs for running a webserver stack. You could find this helpful: http://mina.apache.org/vysper/ which is also by the Apache group. It's an entirely different service (not included in XAMPP) but there's no reason you can't run it on the same server.